# Changing the color of the text on JButton object

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I have a JButton object: `JButton button`;

I add text onto it using: `button.setText("XYZ");`

However, I want to set a particular color to the text. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
button.setForeground( Color.RED );
```

All Swing components support this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You seem to be an expert in Swing.